# Best way to write a function that either returns a value, or a resolved promise

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, higher-order-functions

So I am trying to write a logging HOC that will take a function and log the result of that function.  I would like this hoc to be able to log the result of any function whether that function returns a promise or a value.  This is what I have so far:

```
const logFn = (x) => {
  return   (...args) => {
    const result =  x(...args);
    console.log(`result: ${result}`);
    return result;
  }
};
```

I would like to have this function handle the case when x returns a promise.  I know a hacky way to do it `(typeof result === object && typeof result.then === function)` but this seems brittle.  I am nearly sure there is a more elegant way to do this but I am struggling to find it.

I have included a failing jest test below:

```
import logFn from './logFn';

describe('logFn', () => {

  let outputData;
  beforeEach(() => {
    const storeLog = inputs => (outputData += inputs);
    console["log"] = jest.fn(storeLog);
    require('./logFn');
    outputData = ""
  });


  it('handles async functions', () => {
    const add2P = (x, y) => Promise.resolve(x + y);
    const logAdd2 = logFn(add2P);
    const expected = add2P(1,2).then((data) => data);
    const actual = logAdd2(1,2);

    expect(outputData).toBe('result: 3');
    expect(actual).toEqual(expected);
  })
});
```

bonus points if you can help me clean up the beforeEach.

Comment: What if the function returns an array of promises or an object with properties that are promises? Also with your example you lose the ability to pass the calling context to the provided function. If you want that you'll need to use a normal function instead of an arrow function.

Comment: Those are all great points.  Functions returning arrays of promises or objects with promise properties are not supported use cases here.  I am not married to the arrow function either but I didn't think I would need the calling context.

Answer (score 2):

This has the unfortunate side effect of not logging synchronously, but you could try this.

```
const logFn = (x) => {
  return   (...args) => {
    const result =  x(...args);
    Promise.resolve(result).then(function(value) {
     console.log(`result: ${value}`);
    })
    return result;
  }
};
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve

Comment: The "unfortunate side effect" you mention is unavoidable. You can't block the thread waiting for a promise to resolve, because that's simply not how promises work.

Comment: Also, this _never_ logs synchronously. Nothing wrong with that, but you should correct the misleading statement in your answer. The `console.log()` will be asynchronous regardless of whether `result` is a promise or not.

Answer (score 1):

While this answer isn't much different from [@lemieuxster's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52434444/1541563), there is one major difference.

```
const logFn = fn => function () {
  const result = fn.apply(this, arguments);
  Promise.resolve(result).then(value => { console.log(`result: ${value}`); });
  return result;
};
```

This preserves the calling context if, for example, you want to logify member methods:

```js
const logFn = fn => function () {
  const result = fn.apply(this, arguments);
  Promise.resolve(result).then(value => { console.log(`result: ${value}`); });
  return result;
};

const foo = {
  bar: 'Hello, world!',
  doSomething: logFn(function () {
    return this.bar;
  })
};

foo.doSomething();
```